# Couldn't get the uid in Odoo JavaScript

Tags: odoo, javascript-objects, openerp-8

I'm trying to learn JavaScript for Odoo. I've created a new class in my custom module's js file.

```
openerp.odoojs = function(instance){
    console.log('instance: ',instance);
    console.log('session: ',instance.session);

}
```

This is what I'm getting when I browse the session object in the console.
[image]

But when I try to access the uid or any other attribute or parameter like instance.session.uid, I'm getting it as undefined. Please help! I'm stuck with this. I'm unable proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the **'Backbone.Model'** like **'PosModel'** in **'model.js'** file. Try to define the **'initialize'** function, where you will find two parameters in function arguments as **'session'** and **'attributes'**. Here you can find the **uid** using **'session.uid'**.